# Get and set WPF custom attached property from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, code-behind, attached-properties

I generate objects of framework Rectangle class (which is sealed) and programmatically add them to Canvas. I want to add some information to that objects. Is there such a possibility? I can get and set attached properties in XAML but these is not useful for me.

Comment: Take a look at [Custom Attached Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.100).aspx#custom).

Comment: @ Clemens, if I wrote that I can get and set this property in XAML it means that I can properly register it.

Comment: The section from Clemens link that describes how to do this in code is at: [Section "Attached Properties in Code"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms749011(v=vs.100)#attached-properties-in-code). This is similar to the accepted answer, with additional explanation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can set attached properties in code, something like this:

```
OwningClass.SetMyAttachedProperty(textBox, true);
```

Comment: It's good for any "attached property", presuming you declare it in the standard way.  Here's an example of me using a custom one in code: https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/DialogHost.cs#L231