# Need to modfy the default tab order of child elements

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs, custom-controls

I have custom control like below. When press tab key focus will move in the order elements arrangement.

Query:

When stackpanel receive tab focus I need to change default tab order toggle button present in stackpanel

Default Tab Order:

DockPanel--Border---StackPanel-->Button1-->button2-->button3

Expected Order

DockPanel--Border---StackPanel-->Button3-->button2-->button1

I need update TabOrder based on its parent. Please suggestion solution modify the tab order based on parent

Note: I need UI as like below arrangements, only i need to modify the tab order for buttons

```
<DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Border x:Name="MainBorder">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ToggleButton>Button 1</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton>Button 3</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton>Button 3</ToggleButton>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DockPanel>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'change the order based on its parent?'

Comment: `StackPanel` should support editing the `Children` collection, you should be able to modify the order of the children UI elements by removing all the children and then reinserting the children in the required order, just like you would do in a list when reordering the elements

Comment: with custom panel you can do like ,Overridig ArrangeOverride and modify the order.. in stackpanel, get children, remove them from visualtree and add it in needed index

Comment: I mean i donot know the existing tab index for child element, because the  tab index is assigned based on arrangement, but when stackpanel  recevies focus, i need to update tab order as like 3,2,1, for buttons inside stack panel

Comment: @zafar I want UI to be in the Existing order only, but  I need to update Tab focus order only based on my requirement.

Comment: You have to set the `Control.TabIndex` property on each panel child to  define a custom order.

Comment: To set focus order while pressing tab, modify TabIndex

Comment: @MageshMaggi modify the tab order as mentioned by BionicCode

Comment: @BionicCode If i Set TabIndex = 1 for Button 1 then, tab focus  will directly move to button 1  instead move to parent(StackPanel)

Comment: You can't navigate to any `Panel` or `Border`  using tab. Tab navigation only works for `Control`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments do set the `TabIndex` property. To step within control do use `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation` attached property.

```
<DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Border x:Name="MainBorder">
        <StackPanel KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
            <ToggleButton KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="3">Button 1</ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2">Button 2</ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1">Button 3</ToggleButton>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DockPanel>
```

If you want to modify the tab order at run time I would advice you to create a behavior for it. See [Use of Behavior in WPF MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683504/use-of-behavior-in-wpf-mvvm) To access attached property from code see [Get and set WPF custom attached property from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438746/get-and-set-wpf-custom-attached-property-from-code-behind)